# latexmk with biblatex doesn't raise error for undefined references

Tags: biblatex, latexmk

I would like `latexmk -pdf -Werror` to raise an error when there are undefined references remaining on the last run.  When using `bibtex`, this works as expected.  However, when using `biblatex`, I am still getting a return code of `0` when there are undefined references.

Consider the following `references.bib` file:

```
@book{smith2000,
    author = "Smith, John",
    title = "My Book",
    year = "2000"
}
```

Contents of `main_biblatex.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}

\begin{document}

\cite{smith2000}
\cite{undefined}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Running `latexmk -pdf -Werror main_biblatex.tex` results in the below output with an exit code of `0`:

```
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 7 Jan. 2023. Version 4.79.
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'pdflatex' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "main_biblatex.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main_biblatex.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)))
(./main_biblatex.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
) (./main_biblatex.bbl

Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found
(biblatex)                in the database:
(biblatex)                undefined
(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun
(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.

)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'undefined' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main_biblatex.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


Package biblatex Warning: Please (re)run Biber on the file:
(biblatex)                main_biblatex
(biblatex)                and rerun LaTeX afterwards.

 )</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on main_biblatex.pdf (1 page, 43537 bytes).
Transcript written on main_biblatex.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main_biblatex.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_biblatex.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_biblatex.log'
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'main_biblatex.bbl'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main_biblatex.pdf'
Latexmk: Bibliography file(s) form .bcf file:
  ./references.bib
Latexmk: applying rule 'biber main_biblatex'...
Rule 'biber main_biblatex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'biber main_biblatex' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'biber main_biblatex'
------------
------------
Running 'biber  "main_biblatex.bcf"'
------------
INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'main_biblatex.blg'
INFO - Reading 'main_biblatex.bcf'
INFO - Found 2 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex file 'references.bib' for section 0
INFO - LaTeX decoding ...
INFO - Found BibTeX data source 'references.bib'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'normalization = NFD' with 'normalization = prenormalized'
INFO - Overriding locale 'en-US' defaults 'variable = shifted' with 'variable = non-ignorable'
INFO - Sorting list 'nty/global//global/global' of type 'entry' with template 'nty' and locale 'en-US'
INFO - No sort tailoring available for locale 'en-US'
INFO - Writing 'main_biblatex.bbl' with encoding 'UTF-8'
INFO - Output to main_biblatex.bbl
WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'undefined' (section 0)
INFO - WARNINGS: 1
Biber warning: [194] Biber.pm:131> WARN - I didn't find a database entry for 'undefined' (section 0)
Latexmk: Found biber source file(s) [main_biblatex.bcf references.bib]
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  main_biblatex.aux
  main_biblatex.run.xml

------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "main_biblatex.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main_biblatex.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)))
(./main_biblatex.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
) (./main_biblatex.bbl

Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found
(biblatex)                in the database:
(biblatex)                undefined
(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun
(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.

)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'undefined' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main_biblatex.aux) )<
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/
type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on main_biblatex.pdf (1 page, 43537 bytes).
Transcript written on main_biblatex.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main_biblatex.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_biblatex.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_biblatex.log'
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'main_biblatex.bbl'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main_biblatex.pdf'
Latexmk: Bibliography file(s) form .bcf file:
  ./references.bib
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  main_biblatex.aux
  main_biblatex.run.xml

------------
Run number 3 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "main_biblatex.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main_biblatex.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pdftexcmds/pdftexcmds.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/iftex/iftex.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvoptions/kvoptions.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/kvsetkeys/kvsetkeys.sty))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/numeric.bbx
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/cbx/numeric.cbx)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-case-expl3.sty
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty)))
(./main_biblatex.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/english.lbx
) (./main_biblatex.bbl

Package biblatex Warning: The following entry could not be found
(biblatex)                in the database:
(biblatex)                undefined
(biblatex)                Please verify the spelling and rerun
(biblatex)                LaTeX afterwards.

)

LaTeX Warning: Citation 'undefined' on page 1 undefined on input line 9.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main_biblatex.aux) )<
/usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/tex
mf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/
type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/am
sfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on main_biblatex.pdf (1 page, 43537 bytes).
Transcript written on main_biblatex.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main_biblatex.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_biblatex.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_biblatex.log'
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'main_biblatex.bbl'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main_biblatex.pdf'
Latexmk: Bibliography file(s) form .bcf file:
  ./references.bib
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
```

If instead we consider the below `main_bibtex.tex` file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\cite{smith2000}
\cite{undefined}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{references}

\end{document}
```

and run `latexmk -pdf -Werror main_bibtex.tex`, we get the below output with an exit code of `12`:

```
Rc files read:
  NONE
Latexmk: This is Latexmk, John Collins, 7 Jan. 2023. Version 4.79.
No existing .aux file, so I'll make a simple one, and require run of *latex.
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'pdflatex' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "main_bibtex.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main_bibtex.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./main_bibtex.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `smith2000' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `undefined' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.

No file main_bibtex.bbl.
[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}] (./main_bibtex.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on main_bibtex.pdf (1 page, 19020 bytes).
Transcript written on main_bibtex.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main_bibtex.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_bibtex.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_bibtex.log'
Latexmk: Missing bbl file 'main_bibtex.bbl' in following:
 No file main_bibtex.bbl.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main_bibtex.pdf'
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s):
  ./references.bib
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex main_bibtex'...
Rule 'bibtex main_bibtex':  Reasons for rerun
Category 'other':
  Rerun of 'bibtex main_bibtex' forced or previously required

------------
Run number 1 of rule 'bibtex main_bibtex'
------------
------------
Running 'bibtex  "main_bibtex.aux"'
------------
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)
The top-level auxiliary file: main_bibtex.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: references.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "undefined"
Warning--empty publisher in smith2000
(There were 2 warnings)
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  main_bibtex.aux
  main_bibtex.bbl

------------
Run number 2 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "main_bibtex.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main_bibtex.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./main_bibtex.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `smith2000' on page 1 undefined on input line 5.


LaTeX Warning: Citation `undefined' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.

(./main_bibtex.bbl) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./main_bibtex.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.


LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on main_bibtex.pdf (1 page, 42473 bytes).
Transcript written on main_bibtex.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main_bibtex.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_bibtex.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_bibtex.log'
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'main_bibtex.bbl'
Latexmk: References changed.
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main_bibtex.pdf'
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s):
  ./references.bib
Latexmk: applying rule 'bibtex main_bibtex'...
Rule 'bibtex main_bibtex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  main_bibtex.aux

------------
Run number 2 of rule 'bibtex main_bibtex'
------------
------------
Running 'bibtex  "main_bibtex.aux"'
------------
This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux)
The top-level auxiliary file: main_bibtex.aux
The style file: plain.bst
Database file #1: references.bib
Warning--I didn't find a database entry for "undefined"
Warning--empty publisher in smith2000
(There were 2 warnings)
Latexmk: applying rule 'pdflatex'...
Rule 'pdflatex':  Reasons for rerun
Changed files or newly in use/created:
  main_bibtex.aux

------------
Run number 3 of rule 'pdflatex'
------------
------------
Running 'pdflatex  -recorder  "main_bibtex.tex"'
------------
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (TeX Live 2023/Arch Linux) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./main_bibtex.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2023-02-22>
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2022/07/02 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./main_bibtex.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Citation `undefined' on page 1 undefined on input line 6.

(./main_bibtex.bbl) [1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./main_bibtex.aux)

LaTeX Warning: There were undefined references.

 )</usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/share/
texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fon
ts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/share/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public
/amsfonts/cm/cmti10.pfb>
Output written on main_bibtex.pdf (1 page, 42464 bytes).
Transcript written on main_bibtex.log.
Latexmk: Getting log file 'main_bibtex.log'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_bibtex.fls'
Latexmk: Examining 'main_bibtex.log'
Latexmk: Found input bbl file 'main_bibtex.bbl'
Latexmk: Log file says output to 'main_bibtex.pdf'
Latexmk: Found bibliography file(s):
  ./references.bib
Latexmk: Summary of warnings from last run of *latex:
  Latex failed to resolve 1 citation(s)
Latexmk: ====List of undefined refs and citations:
  Citation `undefined' on page 1 undefined on input line 6
Latexmk: All targets () are up-to-date
----------------------
This message may duplicate earlier message.
Latexmk: Failure in processing file 'main_bibtex.tex':
   Warning(s) from latex (or c.) for 'main_bibtex.tex'; treated as error
----------------------

Latexmk: If appropriate, the -f option can be used to get latexmk
  to try to force complete processing.
```

Is this expected?  Am I using `latexmk` incorrectly?

```
$ latexmk -v
Latexmk, John Collins, 7 Jan. 2023. Version 4.79

$ biber -v
biber version: 2.19

$ pacman -Qi texlive-bibtexextra | grep Version
Version         : 2023.66594-19
```

Comment: Version 4.77 seems to behave as expected (exit code of `12`), while 4.78 does not (exit code of `0`).  I also tested 4.81, and that also returns `0`.  Is this a regression?

Comment: Use the email address from https://www.cantab.net/users/johncollins/latexmk/ to report the bug.

Comment: Email sent.  Thanks @PaulGaborit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This bug will be corrected in the next release of latexmk (4.82).

Meanwhile you can fix it by changing line 5715 of v. 4.81 of latexmk from

```
elsif (/^LaTeX Warning: (Citation `([^']+)' on page .* undefined on input line .*)\./) {
```

to

```
elsif (/^LaTeX Warning: (Citation [`|']([^']+)' on page .* undefined on input line .*)\./) {
```

What happened between v. 4.77 and 4.78 was that I had updated the patterns for detecting missing citations etc in the log file from some very old versions (from before my time) that worked but made no sense.  The revised patterns were correct for standard latex without the use of biblatex.  But they were incorrect for biblatex, which writes slightly different messages.

There are several other problems with latexmk's support of biber, that I'm in the process of also correcting for the next release (4.82).